# MYSQL query (with joins and virtual values)

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 InnoDB tables: **emails**, **websites** and **subscriptions**.

**emails** table has `id` and `email` columns.

**websites** table has `id` and `address` columns.

**subscriptions** table has `id`, `email_id` and `website_id` columns.

What I'm tring to do is supply an email and return a table with columns `address` and `subscribed`. The former is a list of all the addresses in the **websites** table and the latter gets value 1 if the supplied email address has an occurence in the **subscriptions** table with `website_id` set to that website, or 0 otherwise. But I'm willing to retain all the websites even if the user is not found.

The point I'm stuck is where I should change the value of the virtual column `subscribed` from 0 to 1 when that email has that record.

Here's my query so far. Does anybody know how to do this?

```
SELECT `address`, "0" AS `subscribed`
/* 0 becomes 1 for the websites email has subscribed to */
FROM `websites` a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT s.`website_id` FROM `subscriptions` s
    RIGHT JOIN (
        SELECT `id` AS `email_id` FROM `emails`
        WHERE `email`='someone@mail.com' LIMIT 1) e
    ON s.`email_id`=e.`email_id`) l
ON l.`website_id`=a.`id`
```

And here are the example outputs for the desired values for the `subscribed` column:

- If email is not found in the `emails` table all the rows get value 0
- If email is found in the `emails` table...

  - if it is not found in `subscriptions` table all the rows get value 0
  - if it is found in `subscriptions` table, the appropriate address rows get value 1

Let me know if I couldn't wxplain it well. Does anytbody know what I should alter in my query?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should avoid using RIGHT JOINs. They aren't considered good style and in my experience, MySQL runs them a LOT slower than the equivalent left join.

Comment: Thank you. I normally wouldn't use them, either, but I got lost in this query so thought maybe... but thanks to Joe the problem is solved. I got rid of the right join :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT w.address, CASE WHEN s.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS subscribed
    FROM websites w
        LEFT JOIN subscriptions s
            INNER JOIN emails e
                ON s.email_id = e.id
                    AND e.email = 'someone@mail.com'
            ON w.id = s.website_id
```

You could also come up with the subscribed value this way, which is a bit more concise but also somewhat less obvious.

```
SELECT w.address, COALESCE(s.id/s.id, 0) AS subscribed
    FROM websites w
        LEFT JOIN subscriptions s
            INNER JOIN emails e
                ON s.email_id = e.id
                    AND e.email = 'someone@mail.com'
            ON w.id = s.website_id
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your first code works great but I liked the second one better. The issue with the latter is that it returns floating numbers so I made a little addition to your fist line: `SELECT w.address, CAST(COALESCE(s.id/s.id, 0) AS SIGNED) AS subscribed`